# How to put JavaScript into script element without escaping?

Tags: java, jsoup

I'd like to generate an HTML document with JSoup (version 1.15.3). The HTML document should contain script with a comparison.

This is the code to create a script element and to fill it with some JavaScript:

```java
Element script = document.getElementsByTag("head").first().appendElement("script");
script.html("var i=0;if(i<5){alert(123);}");
```

The generated HTML code contains this:

```html
<script>var i=0;if(i&lt;5){alert(123);}</script>
```

In most other cases I expect that JSoup escapes characters like `>` and `<`, but in a `script` element these characters are intended as-is and I do not want them to get replaced by `&gt;` or `&lt;`.

How can I give JSoup the hint not to escape content of a script element?

Comment: does it work if you use the `text` method instead of `html`?

Comment: No, with `text` it's the same result.

Comment: Addition: it also doesn't change the output whether I use output syntax HTML or XML (like  `document.outputSettings().syntax(Document.OutputSettings.Syntax.html);`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DataNode`

```
Element script = document.getElementsByTag("head").first().appendElement("script");
script.appendChild(new DataNode("var i=0;if(i<5){alert(123);}"));
```

Comment: Works as intended. Thank you. Here's the documentation of `DataNode`: https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/DataNode.html

Answer (score 1):

If you use a recent version of jsoup, just calling the [`element.text(...)`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#text(java.lang.String)) method will work. Per the API documentation, that method tests if the input should be treated as text or as data, depending on the containing element type:

```java
Document doc = new Document("https://example.com/");
Element script = doc.head().appendElement("script");
script.text("var i=0;if(i<5){alert(123);}");
System.out.println(doc.html());
```

produces:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script>var i=0;if(i<5){alert(123);}</script>
 </head>
</html>
```

This was implemented in this [commit](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/commit/724b2c5bf576cbd548738756bfe5f7a7b90c6239) and has been in jsoup since 1.14.1 (we're on 1.15.3 as of writing).

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure that the content of every script element is unescaped, I execute a cleanup just before exporting the Document. It transfers text of a script element into a DataNode:

```
    Elements scriptElements = document.getElementsByTag("script");
    if (scriptElements != null) {
        Iterator<Element> scriptIterator = scriptElements.iterator();
        while (scriptIterator.hasNext()) {
            Element script = scriptIterator.next();
            String data = script.data();
            String text = script.text();
            script.text("");
            script.appendChild(new DataNode((text != null ? text : "") + (text != null && data != null ? " " : "")
                    + (data != null ? data : "")));
        }
    }
```

This cleanup in the end is necessary because in the system there is a plugin mechanism for the extension of JSoup documents and I can not guarantee that every plugin calls the right methods. In fact some of the plugins actually just copy html code blocks/templates (with some scripts / styles mixedin) textually into the JSoup document.